# iOS loading custom fonts dynamically error collection retain

Tags: ios, fonts

Single stepping until exit from function `__CFTypeCollectionRetain`

```
 NSData *inData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"NafeesWeb.ttf"]; /* your decrypted font-file data */;
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }
    CFRelease(font);
    CFRelease(provider);
```

I also want to unregister this font after use.

Comment: on this line   if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error))  i am getting following error

Comment: Single stepping until exit from function __CFTypeCollectionRetain

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stepping through or logging the `inData` to make sure it is not `nil`?

You are supposed to use an absolute path with `initWithContentsOfFile:`, so you may not be loading the data in the first place.

Try: `NSData *inData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NafeesWeb" ofType:@"ttf"]];`